# I can't integrate cause of math range error

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, exp

I can't integrate this in python (1/1+t))+(-1/exp(t)) [0,np.inf]

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp
from scipy.integrate import quad

print(quad(lamba t: (1/1+t))+(-1/exp(t)),0,np.inf)
```

It must show Euler constant

[image: This is what i want to integrate]

Comment: two things: `labda` sould be `lambda`; `(1/1+t) = 1 + t` and not `(1/(1+t))` as your latex image shows.

Comment: Could you edit your post in order to add the full trace?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Read more thoroughly before commenting. In the equation (the "latex version"), it is `-exp(-x)`, which is strictly equivalent to `-1/exp(t)`. `-exp(t)` would be wrong.

Comment: @Rightleg removed that comment a minute after i'd written it. thanks for spotting anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, with this integral you will never have the Euler constant.

Euler constant is defined as (sorry I can't post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6iiM.jpg

So you have to change your `lambda` function to the following:

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp
from scipy.integrate import quad
f = lambda t: 1/t * (1/(1+t) - exp(-t))

In [21]: quad(f, 0.0, np.inf)
Out[21]: (0.5772156649015537, 3.613579096292482e-10)
```

The result is `0.5772156649015537` which is the value of the Euler constant.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `lamba` instead of `lambda`, which should raise a `SyntaxError`.

Besides, reading your equation, the function you pass should rather be:

```
lambda t: 1/(1+t) - exp(-t)
```

Try changing your last line to:

```
print(quad(lambda t: (1/(1+t) - exp(-t)), 0, np.inf))
```